# Calling Math Editor

Tags: php, javascript, html, math

Is there is a library for invoking math symbols/formula(not sure what to call), which are design specifically to be added in a websites called maybe in html, php or javascript code.

Just like the button for bold, italic, link, etc. above the textarea in answer/ask ques page(sorry bout earlier), there will be another icon to pop up the match symbols when user click at it..

thank very much.

**Updated::**

Other than these two example, is there any online math editor available?

1. Latex Equaition
2. Sitmo

thank you very much

Comment: Are you just trying to display mathematical symbols and formulas?  "Button bar above" is vague; do you mean SO's button bar?

Comment: Sorry.. i edit my questions ady. it in above the textarea it answer/ask question page in stackoverflow for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this website to develop quizzes which can use math symbols. Which contain built in math function.

http://docs.moodle.org/en/Dragmath

thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a library, except in the loosest sense, but if you happen to mean mathematical symbols for webpages (which can be combined to create formulae) you could start with the World Wide Web Consortium's [Character entity references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) for HTML 4

It's not clear what you meant when you referred to the 'button bar above.'

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [Mathjax to write math symbols to web pages](http://www.mathjax.org)

Answer (score 1):

[jsMath](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/welcome.html) looks like a good solution, the results look [good](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/examples/Struik.html) and it has [broad support](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/browsers.html), though it's still dependent on local fonts and browswers.  There's also [MathML](http://www.w3.org/Math/), but support for this seems to be too thin.