# How to include math Symbols in Editor or Textbox 

Tags: math, symbols

I have to include math symbols in my asp.net

so whatever the symbols  it may be sigma , integral , pie etc..or any

how to write or display the Symbols in asp.net it should be UI  so when the user click the

particular Symbols it will display in the textbox or any editor control..

If anyone have idea let me know...?

thanks.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671943/called-math-symbols-formula-html-php-javascript-a-k-a-math-editor

Comment: I have Checked That's not resolve the issue , even the Posted member was not getting the Right answer.

Comment: @Artelius Unicode 25d4 ◔

Comment: What does is this   Unicode 25d4

Comment: Unicode 25d4 is this character here between the quotes "◔" which is a quarter pie. If you can't see it, upgrade your browser or OS to one with unicode support.

Comment: ok as i am using the math symbol. there is lot more its depend on the problem we have to include the symbol like pie etc... 

if its a Editor like it willl be useful so we have not user 5 or 10 symbols only we have to use all the symbols so if its  UI so Admin can clicking the symbols it wil display it on Editor or Textbox Controls. As i already Checked Latex it will given as image.

Its like full of math problem solving , ie: admin can place the Dropdownlist wherever he wants so there it will show some option by selecting - correct answers - finally user submit it wil show the correct answers

Comment: ..., this is simple video like the same i have to implement check it 

http://s373.photobucket.com/albums/oo173/venkatu2005_troy/?action=view&current=demomovie.flv

But we have to do some more complicated problems like this page

http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/examples/TeXbook17.html

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using ASP.NET you can use the HTML character entity references to display symbols.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

**Updated**

You can just put the special characters into your html code. Prefix the items from the reference with "&#" and suffix with ";"

&#8747; dy K(x,y)&#966;(y) = &#955;&#966;(x)

yields

∫ dy K(x,y)φ(y) = λφ(x)

Comment: Hi Let me know how to use this in asp.net ? 

How shall i display this let give some sample code.  ?