# C# Math graphics library

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, math

I want to create a small math solver application in wpf or silverlight that shows working. Something similiar to what [Microsoft Math](http://www.microsoft.com/education/products/student/math/default.aspx#overview) can do. How do I get those graphics such as the brackets with the ability to stretch vertically based on how many rows are in the equation?

Are there any library that contain these graphics and displaying the steps for .net?

Comment: I'd suggesting editing the title so there's no reference to `icon`. You're not talking about icons, but rather just a graphics library. As starter, you may want to have a look at this question and its links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691982/how-to-include-math-symbols-in-editor-or-textbox

Comment: There is a math equation control at the following link. I'm not sure how comprehensive it is. And if you need it for commercial purposes you have to contact the owner. http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/controlgallery/entry2346.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this easily using [MathJAX](http://www.mathjax.org/) and JavaScript.

Comment: Can't imagine why this answer has been singled out for a downvote almost five years after it was posted.  The answer underneath it, which cited mine, received no such treatment.  Moderators?

Comment: @duffymoi think it's because he went a step further and provided an example

Comment: Did you downvote again, seven years after the answer and 2.5 years since my original complaint?  I'll point out that my answer was the accepted one, regardless of your opinion.

Answer (score 6):

Based on @duffymo's answer, you could load a webbrowser
[WPF Webbrowser](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/01/15/wpf-webbrowser-and-javascript-interaction.aspx) and inject the [MathJAX](http://www.mathjax.org/) library

For reference:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
  <WebBrowser x:Name="Browser" />
</Grid>
```

You can interact with the JavaScript API using this code:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Browser.LoadCompleted += BrowserOnLoadCompleted;
        Browser.Navigate(new Uri("http://example.com"));
    }

    private void BrowserOnLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs navigationEventArgs)
    {
        var doc = (HTMLDocument)Browser.Document;
        var head = doc.getElementsByTagName("head").Cast<HTMLHeadElement>().First();
        var script = (IHTMLScriptElement)doc.createElement("script");
        script.text = "alert('hi');";
        head.appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)script);
        script.text = "alert('bye');";
    }
}
```