# How can i echo mathematical symbols like alpha, beta, summation?

Tags: php, math, symbols

I need to display mathematical function formulas.
For this, how can i echo those mathematical symbols using php?

Suppose i have a textbox on webpage, if someone types something there, then the special unicode characters like alpha, beta, summation or my local language characters will be typed there, can i do something with php to do this?

Comment: see this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671943/calling-math-editor

Comment: I'll just guess that you really need help with this: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use html entity codes to show these symbols.
eg:

```
<div>
    &#931;
    &#945;
</div>
```

Running example here : http://jsfiddle.net/7QBaZ/

Chart of html entities:
http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/symbols.html

However, to show complex formulae,tis is not as easy as putting HTML entities to show mathematical symbols.
You can find some help here to get started :

http://www.zipcon.net/~swhite/docs/math/math.html

http://www.myphysicslab.com/web_math.html

Answer (score 4):

Encode your document in UTF-8 and insert the appropriate Unicode characters: α, β, ∑...

```
echo "α, β, ∑";
```

Comment: How can i type those characters? I don't have those characters available on my keyboard.

Comment: Depends. Windows has the Character Map somewhere in Accessories, Mac OS has the (supreme) Character Viewer. You can also simply copy and paste them from Wikipedia, http://unicode.org or wherever else you can find them.

Comment: I don't want to copy paste, i need to type the code of that character, and php will echo/display it, how can i do it?

Comment: What do you mean you "want to type the code of that character"? There may or may not be a keyboard shortcut to enter that character directly in your OS of choice, I don't know. There are many ways to enter the character. Any way is fine, as long as you can get it into your editor and save the file as UTF-8.

Comment: What does that mean by UTF-8 ?

Comment: You need a basic intro: http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: suppose i have a textbox on webpage, if someone types something there, then the special unicode characters like alpha, beta, summation or my local language characters will be typed there, can i do something with php to do this?

Comment: *sigh* Yes, there's a code sample in my answer. All you're trying to do is output a character. There's nothing special about mathematical symbols. All you need to be able to do is enter the character into your PHP file somehow (keyboard shortcut, Character Map, copy-paste, whatever) and encode the file in an encoding that can encode those characters. Done.

Comment: Why don't you copy the symbols and put it in the array? then if someone types something on your input field, call the array and output it.

Comment: @deceze, how can i check keyboard shortcut, support if someone type CTRL+S, then the summation symbol will be typed in that textbox, how can i check that CTRL+S using php? Should i start a new question with this?

Comment: @prime What do you mean "check CTRL+S using PHP"?

Comment: Keyboard event, pressing CTRL+S (control+s) from keyboard during typing something on textbox. Can we discuss in chat room?

Comment: Total *facepalm* after reading those comments

Comment: @prime Why do you want that? What problem are you trying to solve? If you're trying to display received characters, *how* these characters were entered is completely irrelevant. There will be no trace of a user having pressed CTRL+S to enter a certain character, all you'll receive server-side is the character.

Comment: `There will be no trace of a user having pressed CTRL+S to enter a certain character` I didn't understand that.

Comment: Did you understand the problem? You will press CTRL+S or some predefined, mapped keyboard shortcut/event then it will display/show some mapped unicode chracter on textbox, clicking the submit button, the php will start to work, php will submit that data taking from textbox and display it on webpage, think about commenting for a post.

Comment: @prime Yes, exactly. That's how it works. What problem do you have with the process you just described?

Comment: I haven't yet tried with javascript, i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, yes. The best way I know of is if you echo their Octal or Hexadecimal values.

ie.. `echo ("Octal char = \062 and Hex char  = \x32");`

Comment: That didn't work, that prints, `Octal char = 2 and Hex char = 2`

Comment: They were examples of how to print them...

Answer (score 0):

You can use hexadecimal codes to output the symbols.

http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/greekchart.html

http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/mathchart.html

Comment: Do i have to store those values somewhere? How can i get those values in php to echo it? Like we do echo 'abcd', how can i type those characters?